# Thymeleaf: select a variable by another one

Tags: thymeleaf

This is my model.

```
keys: "a", "b", "c"
a: "bla", "bla"
b: "blu", "blu"
c: "hi", ha"
```

I am not sure how to select the list I like to iterate by the element of another list.

e.g. list x where x is 1st of keys

```
<select>
  <optgroup th:each="k : ${keys}" th:label="${k}">
    <option th:each="m : ${${k}}" th:text="${m}"></option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Here it is **${${k}}** - how do I express this correct in thymleaf??

**EDIT**

Because it was asked in the comments...

I have a

```
Map <String, List <String>>
```

in Java but was not able to put it into org.springframework.ui.Model.addAttributes ().

Not sure but I think it only allows flat Collections.

So I put the list of keys into the Model and also the list for every key.

I would appreciate if I can do it in a more direct way - but not sure how...

Comment: What is your input, in terms of Java types? Is it `Map<String, List<String>> keys`, maybe? Or something else? What output do you expect to get? Show us the expected end-result HTML. There are various answers here on SO which describe how to use Thymeleaf to iterate over a Java `Map` - one of those probably answers your question already.

Comment: Show us the code and the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this:

1. Using the `#ctx` utility object (may differ slightly depending on your Thymeleaf version):

   ```
    <select>
      <optgroup th:each="k : ${keys}" th:label="${k}">
        <option th:each="m : ${#ctx[k]}" th:text="${m}"></option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
   ```
2. [Preprocessing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing):

   ```
    <select>
      <optgroup th:each="k : ${keys}" th:label="${k}">
        <option th:each="m : ${__${k}__}" th:text="${m}"></option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
   ```

That being said, I'm not sure you'd want to do it this way -- why not have a `Map` or some other data structure you've built for this?  You can run into runtime errors and/or security vulnerabilities (such as exposing internal variables when you don't want to) when using these kind of methods.

Comment: I tried with a Map <String, List <String>> but that was not allowed by Model.addAttribute.

Comment: Were you naming your attribute? This one: `addAttribute(String attributeName, Object attributeValue)` -- I'm not sure spring would know the name to use if you did just `addAttribute(Object attributeValue)`.

Comment: @chris01 - then that is probably the question you should ask, with code and the error message. Are you using Spring?

Comment: Yes, I will open another question.